# REXX tool to find table used by cobol code

Tags: db2, rexx

Its Db2.I normally use srchfor text to search which all codes uses table A. and manully read the code to find the table queries done on it.I want to automates it .Is there a way? Can rexx utility tool be made on the same.

Comment: Yes of course there is way and Rexx would be a good tool to access it; What Information are you trying retrieve from the programs, you have not told us that yet ???. For mainframe DB2, you can get a lot of information by accessing the System Tables; the DBA's can help you with That. The System tables may be sufficient, at the very least they will tell you which programs to check,

Comment: Alternatively if you can get a DB2 JDBC driver; The project http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/ has very useful DB2 extensions which will display which programs view / update which tables/fields

Comment: This question http://ibmmainframes.com/about48299.html contains a basic example of access DB2 system information